# when I right click on grid header the menu not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

- I am trying to integrate right click menu to the grid header.
- when I right click on google link its working.
- but where as when I right click on grid header the menu not showing .
- can you tell me how to fix it .
- providing my code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/c7gbh1e9/

```or-tag-here
$('body').on('contextmenu', 'a.test', function() {


  //alert("contextmenu"+event);
  document.getElementById("rmenu").className = "show";
  document.getElementById("rmenu").style.top = mouseY(event);
  document.getElementById("rmenu").style.left = mouseX(event);

  document.getElementsByClassName("k-grid-header").className = "show";
  document.getElementsByClassName("k-grid-header").style.top = mouseY(event);
  document.getElementsByClassName("k-grid-header").style.left = mouseX(event);

  //getElementsByClassName

  window.event.returnValue = false;


});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c7gbh1e9/16/

Answer (score 0):

It's because the event fires when  is right clicked. Change `a.test` to `.test` and add a `test` class on the gried header.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the Fiddle sets the listener on `#test`, but the element has an id of `#test1`. You should fix that first. Then...

`document.getElementsByClassName(...)` returns a collection. if you intent is to set the `className = "show"` on each element with a class name of `k-grid-header` you must iterate over them.

That is most easily done with `querySelectorAll()` because it returns a collection with a `forEach()` method

document.querySelectorAll('.k-grid-header').forEach(el=>{
   el.className = "";
   //... etc
});

Comment: hey i updated in the fiddle...its not working...can you update in the fiddle...its confusing http://jsfiddle.net/whqrwzbu/

Comment: I made significant changes to simply it into a [Simplified, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Here: http://jsfiddle.net/whqrwzbu/23/

Comment: hey can you explain your code so that in future I will implement by myself

Comment: any idea how to achieve this when I slect check box particular column should show and others should disappear. I tried but not working
http://jsfiddle.net/e2Lsjcx0/13/